# Soap UI is displaying black screen, how to fix that

Tags: soapui

Hi I am observing suddenly the soap ui screen in this manner. 
Anyone knows how to fix, or how to close it with saving all the projects.

[soap ui screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UIhN.jpg)

Comment: Try increasing the java heap size.